# How to delete this comma, in a txt file with java, but let this "," comma stay?

Tags: java, replaceall

Hey Friends i m at a java code to replace commas from a text.
I Just want to delete all the usual commas, and let this kind of a comma "," stay.

I start a little bit to code it. But its a little bit frustrated.

Try it with a if and else but doenst work.

```
public class converter{


   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://USers//Sei_Erfolgreich//Desktop//convert.txt"));
       String akhi = br.readLine();


       if(akhi.contains(" \",\"")) {

       }else
           akhi.replaceAll(",", "");
   }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean removing all but quoted commas, or is that comma some weird Unicode fullwidth combining comma presentation form thingy?

Comment: Why not just use a CSV parser and write the output to a file delimited by something other than a comma?

Comment: it is a couchdb export, a csv parser,would be more work than this

Comment: only normal commas should be out which are in a text, commas like this "," shoudl stay, i mean need to stay in the txt file

Comment: @ayhan, +1 for the question. It is very interesting &  i could not do that with single replaceAll by using regular expression. If you ever find that, share it here.

Comment: here this should work

Comment: @VinothS i comment it at last

Answer (score 2):

One work around is to map the characters you want to keep to something else temporarily.

```
akhi = akhi.replaceAll("\",\"", "\uffff")
           .replaceAll(",", "")
           .replaceAll("\uffff", "\",\"");
```

The character `\uffff` is invalid by definition and shouldn't occur naturally.

Answer (score 0):

So like this ?

```
  import java.io.*;

   public class converter{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://USers//Sei_Erfolgreich//Desktop//convert.txt"));
       String akhi = br.readLine();

       akhi = akhi.replaceAll("\",\"", "\uffff")
               .replaceAll(",", "")
               .replaceAll("\uffff", "\",\"");

       File file = new File("C://Users//Sei_Erfolgreich//Desktop//convert2.txt");
       FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
       BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
       bufferedWriter.write(akhi);
       bufferedWriter.close();
   }
```

Comment: Btw, on StackOverflow, people try to not have discussions. You shouldn't post an "answer" that has the words "So like this?" People will not answer you. If you must, you can write a question to Peter Lawrey as a comment to his answer. Or you can start a new question (eg, on how to correctly read and write files). Since Peter gave the correct, general answer you were looking for, you should vote for it and accept it. No need to reply to say thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on regular expressions (supported by `String.replaceAll`) [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

For example, you can use [negative lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). These let you specify the rule "match a comma, but not one preceded or followed by a quotation mark." It will look something like this:

```
string = string.replaceAll("(?<!\"),(?!\")", "");
```

Comment: it wont work. for ex: a,b,c,",",f will become abc,",",f.  He wants abc","f

Comment: @VinothS Yes, you're right. I don't have time to play with it, but I believe there's a way to create an "and" condition.

Comment: @VinothS Try this instead: `string = string.replaceAll("(?<!\"),|,(?!\")", "");`

Answer (score 0):

This one here works very well

```
public class converter{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert.txt"));
            String zeile;

            try {
                File newTextFile = new File("C:/Users/Sei_Erfolgreich/Desktop/convert2.txt");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
                while ((zeile = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    zeile = zeile.replaceAll("\",\"", "\uffff").replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll("\uffff", "\",\"");
                    System.out.println(zeile);
                    fw.write(zeile);
                }

                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
  }
```

Comment: You are not closing your resources correctly. You should use [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). [Another link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html)